# Meteor.js i18n package does not work when deployed with MUP (meteor-up)

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, meteor

A meteor app is using the tap-i18n (https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/) and `tap-i18n`'s `setLanguage` function works on the development system. However when the app is deployed to the production server using `mup`, the `tap-i18n` package is installed but the language does not change when `setLanguage` is used.

On the deployed website, you can run `TAPi18n.setLanguage('en')` but the language does not change.

On their github page, it says that deploying needed additional steps. Could this be the problem? How should we adapt those steps to get it to work with a `mup` deployment or even the `mup deploy` process itself?

Comment: They clearly state: "If you use meteor bundle to deploy your meteor project you'll have add the unified languages files to the bundle in order for it to work. follow these steps: ..." Have you already tried doing this?

Comment: However, I believe that doing this with `mup` might not be as easy ... probably you will need to update `mup` a little. Seems a little too complicated from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

In v1.0.0 of tap-i18n which is available in the new Meteor Packaging System as [tap:i18n](http://atmospherejs.com/package/tap:i18n) it is no longer necessary to do anything when deploying